# Integrate Kura and Azure

Tags: azure, osgi, azure-iot-hub, kura

As I know, we can integrate Kura and Azure IoT Hub.

I followed a tutorial from Microsoft to simulate a device and send data to Azure IoT HUb. Everything is ok.

But when I try to integrate it on Kura.

I followed the tip from Kura to insert external jar ( from Microsoft).

Everything look ok. I exported successful my Bundle.

But when my bundle start, It's not satisfy some conditions with lack class.

Here is the error message:

```
  Instances:
No instances were created because: Can not activate instance of component org.kura.microsoft.simulatedevicesecond.Simulatedevicesecond. The activation throws: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec
```

But the class "javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec" is belong to jce.jar ( existed in java JDK).

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle needs to import the package `javax.crypto.spec`.

Comment: javax.crypto.spec is already existed in Java JDK and I don't need use it directly.

Comment: I'm not wrong. When I add jce.jar from jdk to my libs. I fixed this issue. But the real solution is update kura version.

Comment: So you embedded JCE into your bundle? Nice "solution" ;-)

Comment: No, Embedded JCE just solve this issue, but it still miss another class Deployable which belong to rt.jar. If I add this package, I will face to loader violation error. And The question is why we need both all rt.jar and JCE.jar, It existed on java JDK?. Why we need add them one more. So the root cause not is there and i found another solution as above

Comment: This is the point, you don't need to embed your dependencies because they are already in the platform. Just import them.

Comment: But I want to other bundles reference to my new bundle app. When i choose in add dependences every thing is ok, But when I try to call a void in this bundle, it doesn't find out. Please show me if you know how to do that

Comment: @JameLenon I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question.

I used wrong version of Kura and Kura Workspace.

I used Kura Workspace 2.2 with Kura version 1.4.

It maked this error. Change it to Kura version 2.x.

Everything is ok